# How to sort a string list by a part of the 3rd string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Beginner here:

I'm trying to sort a list of nicknames to the corresponding countries in the same line.
They come in this format:

```
FODORGBR + HU-Szombathely-2

ZSOLDPTE + HU-Debrecen-3

THAUSKTR + DE-Herzogenaurach-1

WRIGHNIL + UK-SuttonColdfield-2

KUROTADR + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1

KLERNMTT + DE-Herzogenaurach-1

BIRKNJHA + DE-Erlangen-111

CANECVAD + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1

MALDESND + DE-Herzogenaurach-1
```

I want to sort it by the country initials (so HU, DE etc.) with a caption.
So something like:

```
DE:

THAUSKTR

KLERNMTT

BIRKNJHA

MALDESND


HU:

FODORGBR 

ZSOLDPTE
```

This is what I came up with do define the countries but I can't figure out how to sort all lines with it.

```
fw = open("NameList.txt")
for line_fw in fw:
    if not line_fw.strip():
        continue
    cross = line_fw.find("+")
    country = line_fw[cross+2:cross+4]
```

Comment: good progress so far. For the next step, see if you can save these things to a list/dictionary. And then think about sorting once you collect all the data. Also, just side note: consider using the `with` statement to open files instead of `fw = open("NameList.txt")`. Something like `with open("NameList.txt") as fw:`

Answer (score 0):

First split the list on `" "` and use `operator.itemgetter` to iterate over last element of list.

Or replace `-1` in `itemgetter` by `3` if country code is always 3rd element in the list.

```
from operator import itemgetter

x = ["FODORGBR + HU-Szombathely-2","ZSOLDPTE + HU-Debrecen-3","THAUSKTR + DE-Herzogenaurach-1",
"WRIGHNIL + UK-SuttonColdfield-2","KUROTADR + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1","KLERNMTT + DE-Herzogenaurach-1",
"BIRKNJHA + DE-Erlangen-111","CANECVAD + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1","MALDESND + DE-Herzogenaurach-1"]

new_list = [i.split() for i in x]
new_list.sort(key=itemgetter(-1))

print([" ".join(i) for i in new_list])
```

Output:

```
['BIRKNJHA + DE-Erlangen-111', 'THAUSKTR + DE-Herzogenaurach-1', 'KLERNMTT + DE-Herzogenaurach-1', 'MALDESND + DE-Herzogenaurach-1', '
ZSOLDPTE + HU-Debrecen-3', 'FODORGBR + HU-Szombathely-2', 'KUROTADR + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1', 'CANECVAD + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1', 'WRI
GHNIL + UK-SuttonColdfield-2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('NameList.txt') as fw:
    for line in fw:
        code = re.search(' (\w{2})-', line).group(1)
        nick = re.search('(\w{8}) +', line).group(1)
        d[code].append(nick)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'DE': ['THAUSKTR', 'KLERNMTT', 'BIRKNJHA', 'MALDESND'],
             'HU': ['FODORGBR', 'ZSOLDPTE'],
             'SK': ['KUROTADR', 'CANECVAD'],
             'UK': ['WRIGHNIL']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for finding the country names looks just fine. One Piece of advice when working with files: use the [`with`- statement](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) instead of `open` and `close`. When using `open`, and an error occurs sometime before `close` is called, it's possible that the file is not properly closed, which can mess up all kinds of things. `with` closes the file no matter what happens inside the corresponding code block (It works similar to `try - finally`, see the above link for more info). So, like this:

```
with open('NameList.txt', 'r') as fw:
    for line_fw in fw:
        ...
```

it is ensured that the file will always close down. By the way, instead of using `line.find('+')`, you can just use `line.split('+')`, which takes away the whole string slicing part.

Now, to your question: there are a few possibilities to use here. The simplest would be defining a **list** for every country, and appending the corresponding names to the right list:

```
de = []
hu = []
uk = []
sk = []

with open('NameList.txt', 'r') as fw:
    for line_fw in fw:
        if not line_fw.strip():
            continue
        country = line_fw.split('+')[1].split('-')[0].strip()
        nickname = line_fw.split('+')[0]
        if country == 'DE':
            de.append(nickname)
        elif country == 'HU':
            hu.append(nickname)
        elif country == 'UK':
            uk.append(nickname)
        else:
            sk.append(nickname)
```

this will return a list for every country, containing the corresponding nicknames. As you see, however, this is very clunky and long. A more elegant solution is using a [**dictionary**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with the countries as keys and a list of the names as values:

```
d = {}

with open('NameList.txt', 'r') as fw:
    for line_fw in fw:
        if not line_fw.strip():
            continue
        country = line_fw.split('+')[1].split('-')[0].strip()
        nickname = line_fw.split('+')[0].strip()
        try:
            d[country].append(nickname)  # if country already exists in d, append the nickname
        except KeyError:
            d[country] = [nickname]  # if country doesn't exist in d, make a new entry
```

which will create a dictionary looking like this (i just took the first few lines to illustrate it):

```
{'HU': ['FODORGBR', 'ZSOLDPTE'], 'DE': ['THAUSKTR'], 'UK': ['WRIGHNIL']}
```

Now, there are more elegant solutions for extracting the countries and nicknames, but some of those have been pointed out in other answers.

Finally, if i got that right, you want to write your results to a new file, or at least print them. Let's say you have a dictionary of the above form. Simply iterate over it's keys via `for k in d:`, add some newlines (`'\n'`) inbetween and use `join` to convert the listsinto one string with newlines between all items:

```
for k in d:
    print(k + ':\n' + '\n'.join(d[k]) + '\n')
```

which will print:

```
HU:
FODORGBR 
ZSOLDPTE 

DE:
THAUSKTR 

UK:
WRIGHNIL
```

by adding `with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:` and replacing `print` with `f.write`, you can easily write this to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Here below is the Snippet which would help you :

```
sample = '''
FODORGBR + HU-Szombathely-2

ZSOLDPTE + HU-Debrecen-3

THAUSKTR + DE-Herzogenaurach-1

WRIGHNIL + UK-SuttonColdfield-2

KUROTADR + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1

KLERNMTT + DE-Herzogenaurach-1

BIRKNJHA + DE-Erlangen-111

CANECVAD + SK-KysuckeNoveMesto-1

MALDESND + DE-Herzogenaurach-1
'''
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

data = sample.splitlines()

elements = {}
for indv in data:
    code = find_between(indv,"+","-").strip()
    value = find_between(indv,"","+").strip()
    if code != '' and code in elements:
        values = []
        values.append(value)
        values.extend(elements[code])
        values = list(filter(None, values))
        values.sort()
        elements[code] = values
    elif code != '':
        values = []
        values.append(value)
        elements[code] = values

print(elements)
```

Output :
{'HU': ['FODORGBR', 'ZSOLDPTE'], 'DE': ['BIRKNJHA', 'KLERNMTT', 'MALDESND', 'THAUSKTR'], 'UK': ['WRIGHNIL'], 'SK': ['CANECVAD', 'KUROTADR']}